# Trying to change the style of element and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

So my script doesn't function properly. It's a simple script. 
What I would like it to do is simply change the style of a element. It's finding the element by the attribute "title" as you can tell.

You can also see what I've tried to do to change the style of the element but no luck. If someone can help me with a quick fix.

Here's my code:

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
if (e.which == 77) {
$("[title=#dc0000]").setAttribute("style", "background-color: #00ff00;").click(); //Change style, & click.
 console.log(""M" Pressed. Changed and clicked.") //Logs. Alerting.
}
};
```

Comment: so what's your actual problem?

Comment: What is `$`? jQuery objects don't have a `setAttribute` method, and the return value of `Element.setAttribute` is `undefined`, you *should* be seeing errors in your console

Comment: My problem is that it's not changing the element's style.

Comment: Replace `setAttribute` with `attr`. Also check devtools console for any more errors.

Comment: Ok. You solved my problem. @wOxxOm.

Comment: Mickael, I've tried yours as well. It does work changing the style, though it does not click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 77) {
        $("[title=#dc0000]").css("background-color","#00ff00;").click();
        console.log(""M" Pressed. Changed and clicked.") 
    };
```

Comment: if i were you i will be using class or id to do such thing